# EF5 code-first Derived class foreign key/reference issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, code-first

I have the following:

```
public abstract class InputBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class InputA: InputBase { }

public class InputB: InputBase { }

public abstract class Data
{
    public virtual InputA InputA { get; set; }
    public virtual InputB InputB { get; set; }
}
```

InputA and InputB both use InputBase's collection of Data.

Data will have an instance of InputA and InputB at all times.

I tried linking this up via:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
    .HasRequired(data => data.InputA)
    .WithMany(input => input.Data)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
    .HasRequired(data => data.InputB)
    .WithMany(input => input.Data)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<InputA>()
    .HasRequired(input => input.Data)
    .WithRequired(data => data.InputA)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<InputB>()
    .HasRequired(input => input.Data)
    .WithRequired(data => data.InputB)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

However, I'm getting a MetaDataException, error 0040: Type Data_InputA is not defined in namespace (...)

How can I make this work? I don't want to have to create separate Data collections on the Input derivates as that wouldn't be logically correct.

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo, but your InputA & InputB properties on the abstract class don't have a property name assigned.  You define the data type it returns and can set but not the actual name that will be references in code when you actually want to access the property  EG: public virtual InputA MyInput1 { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, that was a typo :) just trying to show the concept.

Comment: Why is your data class abstract?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem:

Change this:

```
public abstract class Data
{
   public virtual InputA InputA { get; set; }
   public virtual InputB InputB { get; set; }
}
```

To: If you are worried about the `foreign key`, its alright. `Key` of `InputA Object` is the same as `InputBase Object` since we are using `Inheritance`. Hence, `Data Structure` dictates that we do the following.

```
public abstract class Data
{
   [ForeignKey("InputBase"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public int? InputBaseId { get; set; }

   public virtual InputBase InputBase { get; set; }       
}
```

If your `Inheritance` is `Table per Type (TPT)`,

Do this to derived classes:

```
[Table("InputB")] //This is what your table will be named in your database for derived class
public class InputA: InputBase { }

[Table("InputB")]
public class InputB: InputBase { }
```

Also you don't need this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
.HasRequired(data => data.InputA)
.WithMany(input => input.Data)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Data>()
.HasRequired(data => data.InputB)
.WithMany(input => input.Data)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<InputA>()
.HasRequired(input => input.Data)
.WithRequired(data => data.InputA)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<InputB>()
.HasRequired(input => input.Data)
.WithRequired(data => data.InputB)
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You can remove that section because we have used `Property Mapping`.